# Searching an XML file for duplicate lines or duplicate tags in VI

Tags: xml, parsing, search, vi

I have an XML file that has around 150k records. The format of the record is shown below:

```
<product>
<product_id>1</product_id>
<product_name>ABC1</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>2</product_id>
<product_name>ABC2</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>3</product_id>
<product_name>ABC3</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>3</product_id>
<product_name>ABC4</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>4</product_id>
<product_name>ABC5</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>5</product_id>
<product_name>ABC6</product_name>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>6</product_id>
<product_name>ABC7</product_name>
</product>
```

When i load the above file i get unique constraint violation errors - Meaning that some of the records are using the same product_id 
which database would not allow.

Is there an easier way in VI to parse the file to know/display all the products that are using a non-unique ID (using the product_id tag). As an example, 
the above sample has two products using the same unique ID of 3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that rhe right way to do this is by writing a Perl script to process rhe xml tree and throw meaningful errors. Most likely such a script would make use of an existing Perl packages to handle XMLfiles such as [XML::Parser](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aParser).

Best Regards,
Nadav.

Answer (score 1):

Based in [Nadav's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152662/nadav) suggestion but with a different parser, here it's an approach using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `XML::Twig` module. It prints all repeated *ids* separated with commas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my (@rep_ids, %id);

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => {
        'product/product_id' => sub {
            my $id = $_->text_only;
            if ( exists $id{ $id } ) { 
                push @rep_ids, $id;
            }   
            $id{ $id } = 1;
        },  
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );

printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, @rep_ids;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
3
```